# Packages for market basket analysis in R 3.3.0

Tags: r, version, arules

I want to go for market basket analysis on my products data but I'm bound to use R 3.3.0 version. I am aware of the package 'arules' but it works for R >=3.4.0. I have around 20 columns, each of them representing a product and the cells contain 0 or 1 depending on whether a customer has bought a product. How can I convert these columns into transactions in order to use package 'arulesNBMiner'. Also, is there any other package that can be used in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to convert it to a `list` and then use `as`

```
as(as.list(df1), "transactions")
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 10 * 20, replace = TRUE), ncol = 20))
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It gives an error-  no method or default for coercing “list” to “transactions”

Comment: @RenukaDeshpande  It is working for me.  The `arulesNBMiner` loads `arules` package

Comment: @RenukaDeshpande  Try to install the `arules` by `library(versions); install.versions('arules', '1.5-5')`

Comment: It loads arulesNBMiner, but not arules for me. It says- Loading required package: arules
Error: This is R 3.3.0, package ‘arules’ needs >= 3.4.0
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘arulesNBMiner’ was built under R version 3.3.3

Comment: @RenukaDeshpande  I think the arules is not loaded bcz you have a previous R version.  One option is to update to new R version.  If that is not possible, install the package `versions` and then do `install.versions('arules', '1.5-5')`

Comment: install_version('arules' , '1.5-5') is also not working.

Comment: @RenukaDeshpande  It should be `install.versions`

Comment: It was installed with a warning that package ‘arules’ is not available for  R version 3.3.0. Is there any package other than arules that can be used for market basket analysis?

Comment: @RenukaDeshpande  If 1.5-5` is not available, then try for the earlier version i.e. `1.5-4`

Comment: @RenukaDeshpande  Have you tried that?

Comment: Tried that just now. Worked for the most basic version 1.1-6. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Yes, done that! :)